# MongoDB: Match on multiple but do not include duplicates

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, grouping, partitioning

I am writing a query matches documents for a range of months spanning two years. I want to use an aggregate function on another field after that but do not want to avoid duplicates. For example, I want to total tow fields for the months from October to August starting in 2020 and ending in 2021. How do I exclude the months of January through August of 2020 in my totals? I have the following code so far.

```
[{
    $match: {
        "Calendar Year": {
            $in: [2020, 2021]
        },
        "Month": {
            $in: ["Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan",
                "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                "Jul", "Aug"
            ]
        }
    }
}, {
    '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'Month': '$Month', 
                'Facility': '$Facility'
            }, 
            'Gal_Treated': {
                '$sum': '$MGal Treated'
            }, 
            'Cr_Mass_tot': {
                '$sum': '$Chrome (kg)'
            }
        }
    }

}]
```

Example data structure document:

```
_id:6126a7afe24933f84da03a7f
Calendar Year:1991
Fiscal Year:1991
Quarter:4
Month:"Sep"
Facility:"SVE (A)"
Total mass (kg):140
Carbon Tet (kg):140
```

Expected return:

```
_id:Object
MGal_treated:248.5
Cr_mass_treated:11.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some test data model and show how expected result would be like.

Comment: YuTing Please see the updated post for test data model and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$cond` into `$sum`, and put your `condition` in `if`

```
'$sum':{
            $cond: { 
                if: { 
                    $and: [
                    { "Month": { "$in", ["Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
                                         "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug" ] } }, 
                    { "Calendar Year": "2020" ] }]}, 
                then: '$Chrome (kg)', 
                else: NumberInt(0) 
           }
       }
```

Comment: Will the $gte and $lte still work since the "Month" field is string?

Comment: I changed my answer, use `$in` instead of `gte` and `lte`